# Which general purpose programming languages/implementations compile to C

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages

I'm currently using Eiffel (SmartEiffel/ISE Eiffel) which is compiling to c.

I found it much easier to extend the language yourself with new features or tool support if the output is going into the portable assember language also known as C.

Which general purpose, non functional language have this feature too.

I know that there have been outdated C++ precompilers and i even found an old one for Objective-C.

(I also heared about ((Scheme and Lisp) compilers) but i don't like this (language)).

Please list only FOSS (free open source) projects, as i need to study them.

Comment: Should probably be Community Wiki, as there is no single correct answer.

Comment: The GHC compiler for Haskell can compile to C. But you don't like Scheme and Lisp?! That means you don't understand them :)

Answer (score 27):

Nim is a very modern language that compiles to C
http://nim-lang.org

Answer (score 12):

Well, there are some caveats dealing with things like exceptions and floating point numbers, but llvm can output C (though no one uses it in production so it often lags the main release). That means any LLVM based language that can be statically compiled can output to C, including all llvm-gcc frontends:

- C++ (llvm-gcc/[DragonEgg](http://dragonegg.llvm.org/) and [Comeau](http://www.comeaucomputing.com))
- Fortan (llvm-gcc/[DragonEgg](http://dragonegg.llvm.org/))
- Ada (llvmgcc)
- Ruby ([MacRuby](http://macruby.org/))
- D ([LDC](http://www.dsource.org/projects/ldc))
- Lua ([LLVM-Lua](http://code.google.com/p/llvm-lua/))
- PHP ([Roadsend PHP](http://code.roadsend.com/rphp))

Not all of these have necessarily been tested, and may require some tweaking to make work, but they should all work without too much trouble.

Comment: Well i try to get away from the giant project LLVM (does not install and work easily on Windows) and gcc backend. So this are not really options for me.

Comment: You forgot Cython. Which compiles Python to C. Albeit still using the python standard library which is also written in C

Answer (score 8):

[Vala](http://live.gnome.org/Vala), a language similar to C# which is part of the Gnome project.

Answer (score 6):

[Sather](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sather), [Mercury](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_%28programming_language%29), [Felix](http://www.felix-lang.org), [Seed7](http://seed7.sourceforge.net/) and many others... It is quite common for a compiler to generate C (or C++), often seen as "portable assembly language", which has the additional advantage of relying on the experience of C compiler writers to do the optimizations.

Answer (score 6):

haXe.org: a language that compiles to various languages, including C++.

Answer (score 3):

Fortran (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F2c)
COBOL (http://sourceforge.net/projects/open-cobol/)
Perl (http://www.xav.com/perl/lib/B/C.html)
Matlab

I once knew a guy who wanted to study how to write a parser, but did not want to bother with code generation at that point. So, he got his parser to print out simple statements, expressions and gotos in C. So, that would be a C compiler that compiles to C (albeit very bad C) :-)

Comment: There was also a guy that wanted to write an OO language who took the same approach - you wouldn't believe the trouble it caused.

Comment: @MartinBeckett Bjarne Stroustrup ?

Answer (score 2):

ooc (http://ooc-lang.org/), Virgil (http://compilers.cs.ucla.edu/virgil/overview.html), was old version of Algol-to-C translator (abandoned)

Answer (score 2):

Cython claims to compile Python to C